# Can you accept money for your chametz items during Pesach?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, passover, transactions, selling-mechirat-chametz

You sold your chametz to a non-Jew, directly.

During Hol Hamo'ed, the non-Jew comes to your home and says he wants your $500 single malt scotch, and he writes you a check for it. He walks out with your scotch, getting happily drunk along the way.

Can you take his check during Pesach, or is it in some way benefitting from chametz? If it is, consider that a check provides no actual benefit until you cash it - could you hold onto the check but not cash it until after Pesach.

Answer (score 4):

Being that the non-Jew owns the scotch already, it is perfectly permitted for him/her to take it, drink it, and pay the remainder of the balance to you for it.

Comment: This answer could be improved through the inclusion of some additional details about the mechanics of a standard chametz sale, particularly the concept of down payment with remainder to be paid later.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I posted it more to deflate the situation above, rather than actually make a serious answer out of it (although I will try to add to it after Shabbos, Beli Neder)... :)  Thanks for cleaning up above.